# Eclipse on OS X - no hotkeys in dialogs?

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

The small underscored-letter dialog hotkeys that Windows users are accustomed to doesn't seem to be there in Eclipse running in OS X. Is there a way to enable them?

Example:

Windows: To open the Browse dialog for selecting a package, hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

[image]

OS X: To open the Browse dialog, first check where you are, hit <kbd>TAB</kbd>... wait... hit <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> repeatedly until the correct Browse button is highlighted.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately OS X doesn't have this kind of hotkeys. See https://superuser.com/questions/24159/osx-keyboard-shortcuts-in-dialogs for some possibilities to navigate faster in dialogs.

Comment: Yeah, seems so. I posted a request to add that feature to Mac OS X here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=399554